# Adding new window to MDI on click in PySide

Tags: python, user-interface, pyside

I'm wrinting a program in Python using PySide as GUI creator but I'm stuck now i want to get a new window in the MDI when user clicks something like 'new' button but I'm not able to figure it out how that can happen so need some help... 
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your question is very light on details, I will just give you some links to a simple example application that probably does a lot of what you want.

It is based on [this Qt MDI example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/mainwindows-mdi.html):

[image]

The PySide code itself can be dowloaded from the [PySide Examples Repository](https://github.com/PySide/Examples/tree/master/examples/mainwindows/mdi).

For more examples like this, see the [PySide Examples and Demos](https://qt-project.org/wiki/PySide_Example_Applications).

Comment: Thanks a lot it works had to use _QMdiSubWindow_ class once again thanks for the pointer